# A-Frame + pdf.js: unable to update canvas texture twice, in VR mode only

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, pdf.js

I am using A-Frame and pdf.js to create an application to view PDF files in VR. The application works as expected on desktop, including advancing to the next page of the PDF document and re-rendering to a canvas.

When running in a browser in VR (tested with Quest 2), the first attempt renders as expected. However, when rendering a second document page to the canvas, the new image fails to appear *unless* exiting VR mode, at which point the new texture appears as expected.

I have tried setting the associated material `map.needsUpdate` repeatedly (in an A-Frame component tick loop) to no effect. While experimenting, I also noticed that if you try to render a new PDF page a second time and then another page a third time (advancing by two pages while in VR mode), when exiting VR mode, only the texture from the second time appears; the data from the third render appears to be lost - I wonder if this is related to the primary issue.

Code for a minimal example is below, and a live version is available at http://stemkoski.net/test/quest-pdf-min.html . When viewing the example in desktop mode, you can advance to the next page by opening the browser JavaScript console and entering `testBook.nextPage();` and see that the image changes as expected. You can test in VR mode with a Quest headset; pressing the A button should advance to the next page.

The question is: how can I render pages of a PDF document to the same canvas, multiple times, while in VR mode in A-Frame?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>A-Frame + PDF.js</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent("interactive-pdf", {

    schema:
    {   
        fileName:   {type: 'string', default:"assets/test10.pdf"},
        pageWidth:  {type: 'float',  default: 1200},
        pageHeight: {type: 'float',  default: 1500},
    },

    init: function () 
    {
        this.displayPlane = document.getElementById("plane1");
        this.displayMaterial = this.displayPlane.getObject3D('mesh').material;
        this.canvas = this.displayPlane.getAttribute("material").src
        this.canvas.setAttribute("width", this.data.pageWidth);
        this.canvas.setAttribute("height", this.data.pageHeight);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.textArea = document.querySelector("#textArea");

        this.pdf = null;
        this.currentPage = 1;

        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.worker.js";

        let self = this;
        pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.data.fileName).promise.then( function(pdf) {
            self.pdf = pdf;
            self.render(1);
        });
    },

    render(pageNumber = 1)
    {
        if (!this.pdf)
            return;

        let self = this;

        let text = "rendering page " + pageNumber + " of " + this.pdf.numPages + " on canvas";
        this.textArea.setAttribute("text", "value", text);

        this.pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then( function(page) {

            const pageViewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 2 });
            const context = self.canvas.getContext("2d");
            const renderContext = {
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: pageViewport
            };

            const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

            renderTask.promise.then( function() {
                self.displayMaterial.map.needsUpdate = true;
            });    
        });
    },

    nextPage: function()
    {
        this.currentPage++;
        this.render( this.currentPage );
    },

    prevPage: function()
    {
        this.currentPage--;
        this.render( this.currentPage );
    },

    tick: function()
    {
        // this.displayMaterial.map.needsUpdate = true;
    }

});

AFRAME.registerComponent('page-turner', {
  
  init: function () 
  {
      let bookComponent = document.getElementById("interactive-pdf").components["interactive-pdf"];
      this.el.addEventListener('abuttondown', function(event) { bookComponent.nextPage(); } );
  }

});
</script>

<a-scene>
        
    <a-assets>
        <!-- use to display pdf pages -->
        <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    </a-assets>

    <a-camera></a-camera>

    <a-sky color = "#000337"></a-sky>

    <a-plane id="plane1" material="shader: flat; src: #canvas1;" position="0 1 -2"></a-plane>

    <a-entity id="interactive-pdf" position="0 1 -2" 
        interactive-pdf="fileName: assets/test10.pdf; pageWidth: 1224; pageHeight: 1584;">
    </a-entity>
        
    <a-entity id="left-controller" oculus-touch-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="right-controller" oculus-touch-controls="hand: right" page-turner></a-entity>   

    <!-- text area to print debug text -->
    <a-entity id="textArea" position="0 2 -2"
        geometry="primitive: plane;  width: 3; height: auto"
        material="color: #444444;"
        text="anchor: center; color: #8888FF; value: debug text here">
    </a-entity>

</a-scene>

<script>
var testBook = document.getElementById("interactive-pdf").components["interactive-pdf"];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've heard anecdotally that Quest 2D canvas can be a little fickle. This is just a shot in the dark, but maybe you're re-initializing something inside `render()` that was already initialized in `init()`, or the first call to render? For example, it looks like you're requesting the canvas' 2D context twice. Additionally [I got this error when clicking the VR button](https://i.imgur.com/L9u3t4r.png) when testing on Firefox on MacOS. Not sure if it's related.

Comment: @Marquizzo I tried requesting context just once and reusing it, and also requesting it twice, both resulted in precisely the same behavior, unfortunately. I'm using a Windows PC, tested with both Firefox and Chrome, but I've never seen an error like that after clicking the VR button... I'm not sure what would have caused that, and I have no way to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4457):

> requestAnimationFrame doesn't fire when WebXR is engaged

Its quite relevant because `pdf.js` uses `requestAnimationFrame` by default when rendering the image onto the canvas.

It can be toggled though - the [pages render function](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/api.js.html#line1375) has an option `intent`, which is later on used to determine whether to [use requestAnimationFrame](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/api.js.html#line1507).

---

The sources You use are slightly different (older?), but if you search for creating the `InternalRenderTask` in the `render` function of the `ProxyPDFPage` - it's all there:

```
const internalRenderTask = new InternalRenderTask({
  callback: complete,
  params: {
    canvasContext,
    viewport,
    transform,
    imageLayer,
    background
  },
  objs: this.objs,
  commonObjs: this.commonObjs,
  operatorList: intentState.operatorList,
  pageIndex: this._pageIndex,
  canvasFactory: canvasFactoryInstance,
  webGLContext,
  useRequestAnimationFrame: renderingIntent !== "print",
  pdfBug: this._pdfBug
});
```

---

You can set the `intent` to **print** in your `renderContext` object:

```
// 'interactive-pdf'.render()
const renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: pageViewport,
          intent: "print"
};
const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
```

And it seems to be working properly:

[image]

I'm not sure, if setting the intent to `print` won't cause undesired effects (it affects other settings as well), so disabling `useRequestAnimationFrame` in the source does the trick as well.

Check out [the version with the 'print' intent](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/stemkoski/pdf-viewer/printintent.html), or the one with the [modified pdfjs source code](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/stemkoski/pdf-viewer/modifiedsource.html).

Comment: Ofc If you want me to take down the sources let me know

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. Thank you, Piotr!